# OUTER JOIN with join condition causes unexpected results

Tags: sql-server, join

SQL Server 2008 R2, but likely behaviour is found on all other versions of SQL Server as well.

This may seem obvious, but to me it seems like a bug.

The following query gives unexpected results, here is the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE #Base (
Key1 int,
RefDate date
)


CREATE TABLE #JoinTable (
    Key1 int,
    RefDate date
    )

INSERT INTO #Base
SELECT 1, '2012-05-05'
UNION
SELECT 2, '2013-06-06'
UNION
SELECT 3, '2014-07-07'
UNION
SELECT 4, '2015-08-08'
UNION
SELECT 5, '2016-09-09'


INSERT INTO #JoinTable
SELECT 4, '2012-05-05'
UNION
SELECT 5, '2013-06-06'
UNION
SELECT 6, '2014-07-07'
UNION
SELECT 7, '2015-08-08'
UNION
SELECT 8, '2016-09-09'
```

The following query executes as I would expect, returning the 3 rows that only occur in the base table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Base b
LEFT OUTER JOIN #JoinTable j ON b.Key1 = j.Key1
WHERE j.Key1 IS NULL
```

Now I would like to restrict the rows to those before 1st of Jan 2014. As I understand it, I can take the two approaches below, both should be perfectly viable:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM #Base b
LEFT OUTER JOIN #JoinTable j ON b.Key1 = j.Key1 AND b.RefDate < '2014-01-01'
WHERE j.Key1 IS NULL


SELECT b.* 
FROM #Base b
LEFT OUTER JOIN #JoinTable j ON b.Key1 = j.Key1 
WHERE j.Key1 IS NULL AND b.RefDate < '2014-01-01'
```

However, only the 2nd query returns the data that I want. The 1st appears to ignore the added join condition after the AND in the join line.

Why?

(sql fiddle link [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f712/3))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is how `LEFT JOIN` works.

```
b LEFT JOIN j ON <SomeCondition>
```

would return all rows from `b` regardless of the join condition. Join condition defines/limits only what rows would be returned from `j`.

---

```
SELECT b.*
FROM #Base b
LEFT OUTER JOIN #JoinTable j ON b.Key1 = j.Key1 AND b.RefDate < '2014-01-01'
WHERE j.Key1 IS NULL
```

You can think of it as follows:

1. Go through all rows of `#Base`.
2. For each row in `#Base` find all rows from `#JoinTable` that satisfy the join criteria (`b.Key1 = j.Key1 AND b.RefDate < '2014-01-01'`). There could be no such rows in `#JoinTable`, in this case return `NULLs`. Note, that join criteria doesn't filter `#Base`, it filters only `#JoinTable`.

When you put `b.RefDate < '2014-01-01'` into `WHERE`, then you are filtering `#Base`.

Comment: You are right, of course Vladimir, logically I can understand why this works. In practice though, I think SQL Server should tell you off for doing such a thing - error or provide a warning that including a predicate for the LEFT table in your join condition will do nothing. 

Thanks for your clear explanation though, the actual query I was working on was far more complex, getting my head right through a clear example and answer was what I needed!

Comment: You are welcome. Well, it is just a part of SQL language. You can put any expression in `ON` as well as in `WHERE` and they work differently. By design. That's the whole point of `OUTER` join. I doubt that any RDBMS would ever refuse to run such query - that would be against the SQL standard, but there could be tools that analyse SQL code and provide some recommendations; I never thought about it and I don't know if they exist, but there very well may be. "Static [T-] SQL code analysis"... hmmm... sounds like a good google search.

Answer (score 0):

The first query join is read as "join table #jointable only if #Base.RefDate < '2014-01-01'" which will return rows from #Base with RefDate >= '2014-01-01' in addition to records from #Base which have no related row in #JoinTable.

The second query is read as "return all rows from #Base dated < '2014-01-01' which have no related row in #JoinTable".

I guess you want to replace a not exists query with left join .. where is null. You should check the original query, which one of these conditions:

`... and not exists (select null from #JoinTable j where j.Key = b.Key and b.RefDate < '2014-01-01')` 
for the first query

or `... and not exists (select null from #JoinTable j where j.Key = b.Key) 
and b.RefDate < '2014-01-01'` for the second query.

In conclusion, it is not a bug.

HTH